# How does ssh work when client and host are on the same machine?

Tags: networking, ssh, bridge, x11forwarding

I illustrate my question with the help of docker containers but this example is orthogonal to the rest of the problem. In fact any program that allows the use of bridge interfaces and ssh would do.

I use a Docker container which runs a `sshd` daemon in the background which is spawned by `supervisord` which runs in the foreground. I mainly use ssh to have a secure way of X11-forwarding without having to bind mount `/tmp/.X11-unix` into may container and totally exposing the socket to the container. If I use `docker top containername` right after I started the container I get the following output:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                4732                535                 1                   19:56               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root                4745                4732                0                   19:56               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/sshd
```

which is as expected. Now, I exposed port 22 on the container to port 5000 on the host. Hence, I can login into my container using `ssh -X username@localhost -p 5000`. I know how ssh works when client and host are different computers and on different networks but I have some questions when client and host are one the same computer (in my case client is my normal machine and host is the container on my normal machine). I know that docker sets up a bridge between the physical network device on my normal machine and the virtual network device on my machine.

1. But how exactly do my normal machine and the container communicate with each other? Do they use the IP addresses assigned to them by the bridge device and communicate via those?
2. How are the ports involved in this process do they remove the need to use IP addresses?
3. Is there a most efficient/recommended way of using ssh when client and host are on the same machine and configured in the way I just outlined.

Extensive internet search did not reveal sufficient answers. That being said I, of course, would not assert that such a site does not exist!

Comment: Wouldn't `How do docker containers on the same host communicate?` be a more accurate title for this question?

Comment: No, I don't think so first because its not about docker containers communicating with each other and second because docker containers can communicate with each other and with the host independent of ssh. But I am focusing here on ssh.

Comment: `ssh` doesn't care what happens at the lower layer. I don't think there exist any `ssh`-specific answer.

Comment: Hm... You can generalize this question to any kind of client host interaction on the same machine. How does the connection between the two work and how do the ip and ports come into the picture is pretty abstract. Docker is just here to make a clearer example.

Comment: I agree that this is not ssh-specific. It's about IP, not any particular application.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not follow. How is this simply about ip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does local-only communication works? It's simple: Exactly like normal non-local communication except that the network stack detects that the destination of the communication is on the same machine, so it doesn't need to hand over the traffic down the stack to the physical layer and instead passes it to the receiving part of the IP layer.

Especially that means that IP addresses are still necessary as IP network connections *always* need source port and address and destination port and address - the "special" part is just that source and destination address are the same, in this case `127.0.0.1/localhost`.

From the perspective of SSH or any other network protocol, nothing at all changes.

As far as virtualization is concerned, there are two approaches: Bridged networking and NAT.

- With bridged networking, the virtual machine is a full member of the network, with it's own address and everything. This works as follows:

  - The virtualization software creates a virtual network interface in the host machine that reflects the simulated physical device inside the VM.
  - On the host machine, you create a bridge and bind both the virtual device and the physical device to it. This acts kind like a switch with the physical device as the uplink to the rest of the network.
  - Just like a real switch, the bridge device knows what IP addresses are connected to it and will deliver traffic accordingly and don't sent out traffic out on the wire that is targeted at one of the (virtual) devices connected to the bridge. In the network stack, it's located at the link layer.
- With NAT, you can't directly communicate with the virtual machines and must use the host machine as a router, just like most home networks.

  - You still have virtual interfaces connected to a (virtual) switch. But this switch doesn't act like a bridge and isn't connected to the physical network.
  - The network interface of the host machine is connected to both the physical and the virtual network and acts as a NAT router. You'll have to do port forwarding if you want to talk directly to a virtual machine.

I am not sure exactly how Docker operates, it might be that is uses yet another approach and just directly connects ports on the physical host to ports of the virtual machine without the whole NAT shebang.

In the case of your SSH example, there is actually happening quite a lot in the background:

- If you do an `ssh user@localhost -p 5000`, the network stack detects that this is local and doesn't send out the traffic on the wire. Instead, it sents it out to port 5000 of the local machine.
- The NAT forwarder that is listening on port 5000 sends the traffic to the virtual interface where it is received as normal traffic to port 22 from the virtual machine.

Comment: Docker creates two virtual devices (called "peers") that are linked inside of the host machine's kernel. One of them will reside in the container the other one on the host. The virtual device of the container then gets an ip address from the bridge's range of network addresses and the default route is set to the ip address that the Docker host owns on the bridge. I took this from [How Docker networks a container](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) in the manual. And while I'm typing: Thank you!